# When does the sun rise on stack overflow land? (Or, when does the daily limit reset)

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

I hit my daily limit of up votes, but the message box says "Try again in 3 hours".  That would be 4:30 PM PDT.

Seems like an odd time to reset my daily limit.  Is the daily limit automatically reset on a specific hour or is it per user or what?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow/7238#7238

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *exactly* three hours; it resets at 5:00 PM PDT, which is 0:00 UTC.

Comment: Okay, the UTC makes sense, I figured it wasn't exactly 3 hours, but even 4PM or 5PM didn't click --  but I didn't think about UTC.

Comment: Yep. Keep in mind that it'll change to 4 PM next week when DST ends, though.