# What is the definition of "Day"?

Tags: support, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does a day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start)

For the purpose of calculating the number of days in the profile, what is the definition of "day"? Is this based on a specific timezone? 24-hours from last visit?

Comment: [On what a Stack Overflow day is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start). Additional related links for all kinds of other daily events: [on recent profile activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42963/what-exactly-is-a-day-in-the-recent-activity-area-of-my-profile), [on voting limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27903/when-does-the-sun-rise-on-stack-overflow-land-or-when-does-the-daily-limit-res), [on the daily reputation cap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67480/what-constitutes-for-a-day-as-far-as-rep-caps-are-concerned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a UTC day, same as for the rep cap etc.